# Im(AB) $\subset$ Im A

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let A,B be linear operators over $\mathbb{R}^n$, where $n > 2$. Which of the following statements is correct?
>
> 1. Im(AB) $\subset$ Im A
> 2. Im(AB) $\subset$ Im B
> 3. Im(AB) $\supset$ Im A
> 4. Im(AB) $\supset$ Im B

I know how to disprove 3 and (4). Take

$A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$ and 
$B = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

I need your help to disprove the (2) and prove (1).

Comment: Let $B$ the $0$ matrix, and let $A$ be anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As another answer says about $2$ i will say about $1$..

Let $v\in Im(AB)$ then we have $v=AB(u)=A(B(u))$ for some $u\in \mathbb{R}^n$

Then???

Comment: You're implying that, as operator A is applied last, then $v$ is from its image, right?

Comment: Yes.... So, what do you conclude from this?

Comment: (1) is true. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

2 is diproved by $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ and your $B$. It is not possible to disprove 1 :)

Comment: Thank you. I didn't ask to disprove (1), I asked how to prove (1)

Answer (score 0):

For (1), let $u\in\text{IM}(AB)$. Then there exist $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $u=Ạ(Bv)\in\text{IM}(A)$. Hence, $\text{IM}(AB)\subset\text{IM}(A)$.

For (2) we can choose $A,B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that $(A)_{ij}=1$ for all $i,j\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and $(B)_{ij}=0$ for $i\ne 1, j\ne 1$ and $(B)_{11}=1$.

For (3) we can choose  $B = \mathcal{O}_{n\times n}$, $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\setminus\{\mathcal{O}_{n\times n}\}$

For (4) we can choose $A =\mathcal{O}_{n\times n}$, $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\setminus\{\mathcal{O}_{n\times n}\}$